# Ruby on Rails CoffeeScript failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I have this error which is making it impossible to load my app

```
no such file to load -- coffee_script
  (in /Users/damien/projects/easyJobs/app/assets/javascripts/jobs.js.coffee)
Extracted source (around line #10):

7:  /[if lt IE 8]
8:     = stylesheet_link_tag 'ie.css', :media => 'screen, projection'
9:     = stylesheet_link_tag :application
10:     = javascript_include_tag :application
11:     = csrf_meta_tag
12: 
13:   %body
```

The files are all there but doesnt look like its seeing them for a reason beyond me :/ If anyone knows why this error may be happening let me know would be very much appreciated.

Damien

Comment: I also get this error in the console: WARN: tilt autoloading 'coffee_script' in a non thread-safe way; explicit require 'coffee_script' suggested.

Comment: can you provide your ruby version and your gemfile?

Comment: Rails 3.1.1 and my gem file has the following: gem 'rails', '3.1.1'
gem 'haml'
gem 'haml-rails'
gem 'sass'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'json'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'authlogic'
gem "compass", ">= 0.11.5"

Comment: when you view source do you see the jobs.js file included? Can you follow that link to see the .js compiled file? Can you manually compile the coffeescript?

Answer (score 15):

Try adding to your `Gemfile:

```
group :assets do
  gem 'coffee-rails'
end
```

More info [here](https://github.com/rails/coffee-rails)

Comment: I have mine in the assets group and still get the same error on Heroku

Comment: I resolved this by placing this in application.rb file require 'coffee-rails'